# How to fix: No samples will be generated with the provided ratio settings. (imblearn)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, resampling, imblearn

I have this code:

from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN

```
Y = df.target
X = df.drop('target', axis=1)

ad = ADASYN()
X_adasyn, y_adasyn = ad.fit_sample(X, Y)

getting this error:

ValueError: No samples will be generated with the provided ratio 
settings.
```

Comment: There is  a issue with their function and its default parameters it seems. The ADAYSN function with default parameters itself is not working.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this problem? I am having the same issue

Comment: Yeah, me too. What's the solution?

Comment: I obtained this error when I accidentally ran ADASYN on a dataset that was already balanced.

Comment: What's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a two. There is [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/blob/master/imblearn/over_sampling/_adasyn.py) and it explicitly says:

```
if not np.sum(n_samples_generate):
                raise ValueError("No samples will be generated with the"
                                 " provided ratio settings.")
```

but, yeah......#

Comment: Can you provide what exactly you are trying to explain here

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too, finally i solved it!

1. you should use sampling_strategy instead of ratio
2. sampling_strategy='minority'

I tried other options such as 'not_majority' ,'auto' and dictionary form, all of them gave the following error

> Value Error: No samples will be generated with the provided ratio settings

but 'minority' worked.